# Understanding a step in a proof that $(a\times b)'=(a'\times b)+(a\times b')$.

Tags: analysis, derivatives, vector-spaces, proof-explanation, cross-product

There is a step in [this](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Derivative_of_Vector_Cross_Product_of_Vector-Valued_Functions/Proof_2) derivation of the derivative of the vector product of two differentiable functions that I do not understand: why is

\begin{split}
\lim_{h\to 0} a(x+h)\times \frac{b(x+h)-b(x)}{h} = \left(\lim_{h\to 0}a(x+h)\right)\times \left(\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{b(x+h)-b(x)}{h}\right)?
\end{split}

Comment: Do you already know that limits of vector values functions can be computed one coordinate at a time?  Do you already know that for real valued functions $f$ and $g$, that $\lim_{x\rightarrow a} (fg)(x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow a} f(x) \lim_{x\rightarrow a} g(x)$ provided both limits on the right exist?

Answer (score 0):

The cross product is a linear transformation, and it is therefore continuous as $a$ and $b$ are differentiable.

You can basically think of the cross product as a standard multiplication.